# Is there a way to use a third party gem in a custom download strategy for homebrew

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm setting up a company internal tap for homebrew. Since the archives are uploaded to a google drive, I need to implement a custom download strategy for that. In that download strategy, I want to use a third party ruby library, but I haven't figured out how to install the gem before the download strategy is called.

I've already tried to install the dependency with 'gem install ...', before running 'brew install my-formula'. But this does not seem to work.

Is there a way to use third-party libraries in the custom download strategy or is this not possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homebrew uses its own set of gems to isolate it from system or user-installed gems. To set up a gem that's visible from brew, in your custom download strategy run:

```rb
Homebrew.install_gem! "my_gem"
require "my_gem"
```

If you need a binary from the gem use `install_gem_setup_path!` instead.

Note that this is an internal Homebrew API and could change at any time. You should also ensure that the gem doesn't conflict with any gems that Homebrew itself depends on.